# Using subquery value as table name

Tags: mysql

Here is a problem which is not working for me in the way I expected. This is the query

```
SELECT  `table_name` 
FROM    `category` 
WHERE   `id` = ( SELECT `category_id` 
                 FROM    `assets` 
                 WHERE   `id` = '24028'  )
```

which is returning the value `photos` which I need to use as a table name,

[image]

from where I need to retrieve final values. So I have used it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ( 
         SELECT  `table_name` 
         FROM    `category` 
         WHERE   `id` =  ( SELECT `category_id` 
                           FROM   `assets` 
                           WHERE `id` = '24028'
                          )
       )
```

But this returns the error

> #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

So, have used it like,

```
SELECT * 
FROM  (
        SELECT `table_name` 
        FROM   `category` 
        WHERE  `id` = (  SELECT `category_id` 
                         FROM   `assets` 
                         WHERE  `id` = '24028' )
       ) as `photos`
```

But again it is returning the same value as in the previous image. But what I am expecting is it should return the value of:

```
SELECT * FROM `photos`
```

where photos is the value returned by the subquery.

Comment: How many "table_name" possibilities are there a few, or a LOT of them.

Comment: Exactly 5 possibilities are there. But one at a time..

Answer (score 4):

By the looks of it, you are trying to build a query with a dynamic 'FROM' table name. The only way to do this is to build the SQL in code, or to use a prepared statement:

```
DELIMITER //; 
SET @s := CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', (SELECT  `table_name` FROM `category` WHERE `id` = (SELECT `category_id` FROM `assets` WHERE `id` = '24028'));

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;

EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
//
```

Comment: 1st query again returning the same value, 2nd query is invalid since i need to use a value from table `category` to substitute in another query..

Comment: @Udhay in your procedure, right before 'EXECUTE stmt;', you can put: 'SELECT @s;' to see what the concatenated query looks like for debug purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Then per your comment answer, if you are only ever dealing with one possible "table_name", why not join directly to it

```
select 
      A.ID,
      A.Category_ID,
      C.Category,
      TP.*
   from
      assets A
         JOIN Category C
            on A.ID = C.ID
         JOIN tbl_photo TP
            on A.ID = TP.ID
   where
      A.ID = '24028'
```

Comment: The problem here is that the value `tbl_photo` need to get again from a query only.. So we cannot substitute it directly. :(

Comment: @Udhay, I agree with your solution otherwise with dynamic-sql.  However, in my question to the OP, they responded there was only one "table" that would be a result, hence tbl_photo and my response to just use it directly.

Comment: i changed that. Before i meant only 1 possibility all the time.. :)

Comment: @Udhay, then you will need something like your solution of dynamic-sql